# Android Lollipop recents style ''DeckView'' for lower SDK

Tags: android, user-interface, android-5.0-lollipop, material-design

I found a Github repo which implements a ViewGroup that mimics Android Lollipop Recents screen layout. However its min SDK is 21... How to make it available for SDK 16?

Special thanks to vikramkakkar!!
Github repo

Comment: Lower the `minSdkVersion` to 16. Fix all the Lint errors that occur, if any. Then try it and debug the results.

Comment: I've done this before, however there're more and more bugs...

Comment: Then perhaps you should take this up with the developer of this code. It has been published for only 8 hours, it appears. It is thousands of lines of code, and it is rather unlikely that anyone here is going to review those all for you.

Comment: Github repo [link](https://github.com/vikramkakkar/DeckView)

Comment: Okay......thank you all the same

Comment: @TonyGuo, Have you got any solution ?